# serviceAccount.json needed even if hitting publicly readable resource?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a server component (node.js) that is connecting to my firebase instance. I have supplied the init function a serviceAccount.json file and it works fine.

The server component is accesssing one publicly readable resource in my firebase db. I was hoping to not have to include a serviceAccount.json file for security reasons on the machine.

If my service is accessing publicly readable resources on firebase, is a serviceAccount.json file still required?

Comment: Hey Roy, this is currently required but we're working on updating the SDK so that's no longer the case. I don't have a specific timeline, but we are aware of it and improvements are coming.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the head's up. Looking forward to when this requirement is dropped!

Comment: @MichaelBleigh any updates on this?

Comment: Just that we're working on it.

Comment: Aaaaand it's out! [3.3.0 supports Node.js client auth](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js)

Comment: Awesome! thanks @MichaelBleigh!